# Демонизация python бота в systemd в его venv

Tags: python, linux, debian, systemd

всем хорошего дня, прошу помочь в следующем
Имеется debian
Имеются дериктории
С venv `/home/vladsu/.virtualenvs/vlad/bin/activate`
C ботом `/home/vladsu/SM_8ject/SM-8/SM_8.py`
Файл службы в /etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description=SM_803
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/vladsu/SM_8ject/SM-8
ExecStart=/home/vladsu/.virtualenvs/vlad/bin/python3 /home/vladsu/SM_8ject/SM-8/SM_8.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=240
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Но почему-то бот не видит зависимостей в своей директории
И как указать файл для логов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий пример

```
[Unit]
Description=Otomoto.pl ad publicher and remover
StartLimitIntervalSec=1h
StartLimitBurst=60

After=postgresql@14-main.service
Requires=postgresql@14-main.service

OnFailure=fail@%i.service
StartLimitIntervalSec=10 min
StartLimitBurst=10

[Service]
Type=simple

User=developer
Group=developer

# ===  На самом деле, ответ на Ваш вопрос здесь ===

Environment=VIRTUAL_ENV=/srv/smai/venv
Environment=PYTHONPATH=/srv/smai
ExecStart=/srv/smai/venv/bin/python /srv/smai/portals/publishing/tasks/%i/run.py
# ==============================

ExecStop=/srv/smai/venv/bin/python /srv/smai/extras/services/exec_stop.py %i


WatchdogSec=3600

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

LogLevelMax=err
SyslogLevel=err

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Полагаю Ваш файл должен выглядеть так

```
[Unit]
Description=SM_803
After=network.target

[Service]
# Запуск от root производится по умолчанию
# User=root
# Group=root

Environment=VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/vladsu/.virtualenvs/vlad
Environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/vladsu/SM_8ject/SM-8

# WorkingDirectory=/home/vladsu/SM_8ject/SM-8
ExecStart=/home/vladsu/.virtualenvs/vlad/bin/python3 /home/vladsu/SM_8ject/SM-8/SM_8.py

Restart=always
RestartSec=240

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, протестирую завтра!